# Passing two or more dimensional arrays to lua

Tags: luatex, arrays, lua

I can write:

```
 \def\myarray{{Nrs,1,2,3}}
```

then I can call lua:

```
  \luadirect{myfunc(\myarray)}
```

and access the values in the array/table.

How would one do it for multidimensional ones?

I initially thought to define a multidimensional array in Tex, but I googled and search through all the pdf docs and did not even find the definition of an array.  So now I decided my only option would be:

```
 \def\myarray_a{{name,1,2,3}}
 \def\myarray_b{{name_b,1,4,5}}
 \luadirect{myfunct(\myarra_a,\myarray_b)
```

That should work fine, but I still would like to know if there is another way.

---

I wanted to pass a n X m array from lualatex to lua.

I google and found somewhere to define an array in latex you do:

```
   \def\myarr{{1,2,3}}
```

that I used before, but I could not figure out how to pass a n x m array.  So I asked and then also experimented.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatextra}

\begin{luacode*}
 function atest(arrs)
   tex.print('type of parameter received: '..type(arrs)..'; containing: \\par')
   for i,v in ipairs(arrs) do
     tex.print('i='..i..', type='..type(v)..', name='..v.name..', v[1]'..v[1]..'\\par')
     v[1]=v[1]*2;
   end
 end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\def\flowa{{
    {name="Arr1",1,2,3},
    {name="Arr2",4,5,6}
    }}
\hrulefill

\textbf{\underline{The values:}}\
\flowa\
\textbf{\underline{As seen by lua:}}\
\luadirect{atest(\flowa)}

\hrulefill

\textbf{\underline{Passing by reference (no changes):}}\
\flowa
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: the result]

but it is, as shown, passing by value.

Comment: As Caramdir says. But why it does not work is really simple: all three uses of `\flowa` instantiate an independent anonymous array. If you want to see any kind of persistent effect, you have to store the array in an actual variable.

Comment: @theo Your suggestion worked.  It just means one has to handle it correctly in lua.  I did not know how to pass and handle it correctly in lua.  I would have liked to change the the array passed to lua. **_If you feel I should revoke the question I can, but the interfaces between lualatex and lua is not very well documented._**

Comment: I moved your additional post now to the answer. Please provide further information by updating the answer, not by posting "answer" posts. The question is fine, no need to delete it.

Comment: @Taco: Could you update your answer so that Louis can accept it.

Comment: I'm working on questions and assignments that I could change just a few numbers and if I add a flag the new question and its correct answer is provided accurately.  I previously used spreadtab and numprint, but the rounding comes in too soon.  So with this technique and with my other questions and lua I can now produce questions with different numbers without going through the whole process again. (I will next explore using AEB-pro or other similar js-solutions).

Comment: I think you are confusing things here. your `\flowa` macro is expanded and passed to lua, what lua sees is `{{name="Arr1",1,2,3},{name="Arr2",4,5,6}}`, if you want to change the macro then you have to feed it back to TeX using `tex.sprint("\\def\\flowa{foo}")` or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial response was:

```
\def\myarray{{{name,1,2,3}, {name_b,1,4,5}}}
```

but that does not actually help you, looking at your edits to the question.

This definition indeed passes a two-dimensional array, but it does so using concrete values (a 'literal'). Each use of `\myarray` is then completely unrelated from the other uses of`\myarray`, so not a single change will be permanent.

If you want to pass a reusable two-dimensional array, you have to use a lua variable (code below). This is not something special in the luatex interface, it is standard programming: you cannot pass by reference unless there is something that can actually *be* (de)referenced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatextra}

\begin{luacode*}
 function atest(arrs)
   tex.print('type of parameter received: '..type(arrs)..'; containing: \\par')
   for i,v in ipairs(arrs) do
     tex.print('i='..i..', type='..type(v)..', name='..v.name..', v[1]'..v[1]..'\\par')
   end
 end
function achange(arrs)
   for i,v in ipairs(arrs) do
     v[1]=v[1]*2;
   end
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
flowa = {{name="Arr1",1,2,3},
         {name="Arr2",4,5,6}}
\end{luacode*}
\hrulefill

\textbf{\underline{The values:}}\\

\luadirect{atest(flowa)}

\textbf{\underline{As seen by lua:}}\\

\luadirect{achange(flowa)}
\luadirect{atest(flowa)}

\hrulefill

\textbf{\underline{Passing by reference (no changes):}}\\

\luadirect{atest(flowa)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might work, in a previous attempt I tried something similar and did not get joy.  I will come back.

Comment: It works for Lualatex, but I still can't get the passing to lua correct.

Comment: @Louis: perhaps you should post a more complete example of what exactly it is that you want to achieve and is not working for you.

Comment: TNX.  It seems the best option would be to pass the name of the array to lua, else it would not know what to define.